# Merging two query sets data in get_context

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this get_context method:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super(IndexPage, self).get_context(request)
    context['my_data'] = MyPage.objects.live()
    context['my_date'] = MyDate.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return context
```

I want to use this to list all dates to certain events on the page.
I tried a nested for loop in my template to access both my_data and my_date but that wasn't a successful solution.

I'm guessing I need to merge these to contexts but I couldn't find any solutions for this...

Does any of you know a solution for this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show, for example with some sample data and expected output, what exactly you aim to do?

Comment: ExampleTitle(comes from my_data), 19.12.2018 17:00 (comes from my_date), www.example.com(comes also from my-date). My goal is to list out all events, with title, date and an external link.

Comment: And in the template something like {% for data in mymergeddata %} data.title, data.date, data.link. something like this